# Which JVM version will CIDER run under on Windows

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen, cider

Is there a way to force CIDER to use a particular version of the JVM?

I've been updating a number of projects to use the recently released Java 8 including some Clojure projects that depend on Java interop. However, I've run into some problems with some tools during development. One of those is when using CIDER from Emacs. I can't seem to get it to use a Java 8 JVM.

I have JDK versions 1.7.0_17, _21, _25, _40, _45, _51, and 1.8.0 installed on my system for compatibility testing.

When I launch a CIDER REPL and check the Java version, I see this:

```
; CIDER 0.6.0alpha (package: 20140322.332) (Clojure 1.6.0, nREPL 0.2.3)
eight-queens.core> (System/getProperty "java.version")
"1.7.0_25"
```

I saw similar results when using nREPL, before updating to CIDER. I see similar results when using the REPL within Light Table. Things work as expected using a Clojure REPL launched from the command line.

My Java-related environment variables include:

PATH contains: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\`

JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0`

LEIN_JAVA_CMD: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\java`

(Leiningen launched from a command shell within Emacs produced a similar problem before adding the LEIN_JAVA_CMD environment variable. Oddly, adding the environment variable changed the version of the JVM used by CIDER. Before adding the environment variable, it reported using version 1.7.0_40.)

I haven't found anything that seems to be relevant in the Windows registry.

Is there some way to force CIDER to run with a particular JVM short of uninstalling everything else?

Answer (score 1):

`CIDER` (or `cider-jack-in` to be more specific) uses `lein` to start the REPL (using the `lein repl` command). I'm not sure how the Windows `cmd.exe`, but I assume you haven't set `LEIN_JAVA_CMD` as a global env variable and that's why it doesn't affect the `cmd.exe` shell Emacs spins for `lein repl`.

Comment: As stated in the OP, the `LEIN_JAVA_CMD` environment variable has been set to point to Java 8 already. Running `lein version` at the Windows CLI and in the Emacs shell both produce `Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.8.0 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM` as expected and desired, but the CIDER (and nREPL and LightTable) still report that they are running under the older JVM. Weird, huh?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you've set it in a shell-local manner, therefore my comment. I'm CIDER's developer, but I don't use windows and my knowledge of its shell is limited. I guess you can play with `cider-server-command`, but I can think of nothing else.

Comment: Thanks, Bozhidar. It was a forgotten `java-cmd` setting in the user profile in `profiles.clj`. Not sure how it got there as it was present on multiple systems. Now, on to figuring out why the Light Table InstaRepl is doing something similar.

Comment: This is wrong. CIDER uses boot if the project is using that.

Comment: It wasn't wrong when I wrote it. ;-) Now CIDER also supports gradle and tools.deps, btw.

Comment: Thank you. Ran into the same issue on windows 10 where I had multiple versions of java installed. Only after setting LEIN_JAVA_CMD, emacs shell used the correct version of java matching JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME.